# jpa 2.0 persistence: create and update dilemma

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

I am using JPA 2.0 with hibernate as the jpa-provider. The direction for my project is to keep the DAO's JPA - implementation neutral. So, I cant use hibernate session object or anything that is specific to hibernate. We have quite a large number of lookups and these lookup values are supposed to be periodic by that i mean they largely remain constant for a period example, say we have Currency lookup table

```
Currency code --> Drachma
Description --> Greece
From date --> 01-Jan-1960
To date --> 01-Nov-2005 (this is just an example)

Currency code --> Euro
Description --> Greece
From date --> 02-Nov-2005
To date --> null (null indicates until today)
```

I have designed a base lookup class which looks like this for all the lookups

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseLookupEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
private String code;

@Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
private String description;

@Column(name = "from_date", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fromDate;

@Column(name = "to_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date toDate;

// getters and setters
```

The dilemma is

Given that the service layer receives new instances from the client with no identity field, for each Create or Update of an entity which contains n number of such periodic lookup codes, do I need to query all of these lookup tables explicitly to see if these values exists, and if they exist and require updating, update the to_date column and then create a new lookup entry.

Do I need to do this DIY logic or is there a mechanism in JPA that i could use to minimise the effort?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism to do what you want, but it's not really difficult.

1. Execute a JPQL query to get all the values whose code is in the set of codes you receive and whose toDate field is null: `select c from Currency c where c.code in (:codes) and c.toDate is null` (make sure that the number of codes isn't larger than the database limit for an `IN` clause, though. If so, execute multiple queries)
2. Build a `Map<String, Currency>` from the list of currencies found (the key of the map being the code of the currency)
3. Iterate over the currencies to update. For each currency, find its persistent version in the map. If in the map, update its toDate field
4. Create a new currency instance and persist it.

This process could easily be made generic for all implementations of your base class.